# Dynamically using params for relationship in Neo4jClient

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I am trying to use params to pass in relationship types dynamically with Neo4jclient but it didn't seem to work. Is this possible? Or what would be the equivalent? Basically I am trying to write a utility method to relate two nodes together by simply passing in two node Id and a relationship. I could potentially hard coded it but I am afraid that is against the best practice and vulnerable to injections. Thanks.

```
    public static async Task<string> AddEdge(string node1Id, string relatioinship, string node2Id, bool directed = false)
    {

            await NeoClient.Cypher
                    .Match("(n1)", "(n2)")
                    .Where((BaseObject n1) => n1.Id == node1Id)
                    .AndWhere((BaseObject n2) => n2.Id == node2Id)
                    .CreateUnique("n1-[:{sRelationName}]->n2")
                    .WithParams(new {sRelationName = relatioinship})
                    .ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync();
            return node1Id;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can create a relationship *name* via parameters, the only way I've ever seen this done in `C#` is to to use `string.Format` for the `.CreateUnique`.

If you're worried about injection, one solution could be to use an `Enum`, so:

```
public enum Relationships { Rel_One, Rel_Two }

public static async Task<string> AddEdge(string nodeId1, Relationships relationship, string nodeId2)
{
    if(!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Relationships), relationship))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("relationship", relationship, "Relationship is not defined.");
```

That way if someone tries to pass in a `relationship` you're not using i.e. trying something like `AddEdge("blah", (Relationships) 200, "blah2");` you can ignore it.

One nice thing you get from this is that you can use the `enum` directly in your format:

```
...CreateUnique(string.Format("n1-[:{0}]-n2", relationship))
```

provided you name your values in the `Relationships` enum as you want them:

```
public enum Relationships {
    HAS_A,
    IS_A
    //etc
}
```

Another bonus is that you don't have to worry about misspelling, as you can use the `Relationships` enum throughout your code for querying.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I looked at the neo4j document more carefully and I think it can't be done by Cypher queries as well. I do use enum in code just not the quick test I did. Appreciate your help!